# Get Dialect within some class inside Spring MVC + Hibernate application

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, spring-mvc

I have Hibernate Transaction manager configured inside Spring MVC controller.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1/doolloop2" />
  <property name="username" value="doolloop2" />
  <property name="password" value="doolloop" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
     <property name="mappingLocations">
      <list>
        <value>WEB-INF/mapping/User.hbm.xml</value>
      </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
 <props>
  <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop> 
  <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop> 
  <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop> 
  </props>
  </property>
</bean>
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

In Addition, I have some class which needs to get Hibernate Dialect inside on of it method.
Is class is not Configured as bean inside Spring Framework.

How can I access Hibernate Dialect property from this class? I believe it should be some static class,but I don't know how can I do it. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could separate the properties from the spring config.  Put them in a properties file, then reference that in a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer bean ( http://almaer.com/blog/spring-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-a-nice-clean-way-to-share ).  Then you could inject that value into whatever bean it is that you need the value in the same way you are injecting it into the sessionFactory bean.